# trying making a like button in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I press the button of the likes nothing happens
can you help ?
and which is better ? to make it like this way or to make it a href button
and but the href link to the function.
when I call function via the url an error accrued

```
Object of class profiles could not be converted to string
```

**Ajax**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#likebtn").click(function() {

      $.post(
        "<?php echo site_url('profiles/addlike'); ?>",
        function(data) {

          if (data.st == 0) {
            $('#likedata').html(data.msg);
          } else if (data.st == 1) {
            $("#Likes").text(st.numLikes);
          }
        },
        'json'
      );
      return false;
    });


  });
</script>
```

**View**

```
<p> <input type="button" id="likebtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="إعجاب"></p>
<span class="label label-default" id="Likes"><?php echo $numlikes; ?></span>
<div id="likedata"></div>
```

**Model**

```
    public function checklike($user_id, $profile_id) {
        $condition = "user_id =" . "'" . $user_id . "' AND " . "profile_id =" . "'" . $profile_id . "'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('likes');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function addlike($user_id, $profile_id) {
        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'type' => 'profile',
            'profile_id' => $profile_id
        );
        $this->db->insert('likes', $data);
    }

    public function read_user_information_profile($profile_id) {
        $condition = "user_id =" . "'" . $profile_id . "'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function likes_profile($profile_id) {
        $this->db->count_all();
        $this->db->from('likes');
        $this->db->where('profile_id', $profile_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class profiles extends CI_Controller {

    public $profile_id;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->profile_id = $this->uri->segment(2, 9);
        $user_id = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in'] ['user_id']);
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->load->model('shoghl_profilat_model');
        $data = array();

        $result = $this->shoghl_profilat_model->read_user_information_profile($this->profile_id);
        $countlike = $this->shoghl_profilat_model->likes_profile($this->profile_id);
        $countads = $this->shoghl_profilat_model->ads_profile($this->profile_id);
        $level = $this->shoghl_profilat_model->level_profile($this->profile_id);


        $data = array(
            'username' => $result[0]->username,
            'fname' => $result[0]->fname,
            'mob' => $result[0]->mob,
            'lname' => $result[0]->lname,
            'numlikes' => $countlike,
            'numads' => $countads,
            'levelname' => $level
        );
        $this->load->view('profiles_view', $data);
    }

    public function addlike() {
        $checklike = $this->$this->shoghl_profilat_model->checklike($user_id, $this->profile_id);
        if ($checklike == FALSE) {
            $this->shoghl_profilat_model->addlike($user_id, $this->profile_id);
            $numLikes = $this->shoghl_profilat_model->likes_profile($this->profile_id);

            $output = array('st' => 1);
            echo json_encode($output);
        } else {

            $outputS = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => "you already likes this profile");

            echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Error says that `$numlikes` is not string but an object. You can check it with `var_dump($this->shoghl_profilat_model->likes_profile($this->profile_id));exit;` after loading model in your controller and see what is output.

Comment: @Tpojka the output is -> int 1

Comment: Do you have form with action in it around input field?

Comment: no, just the button @Tpojka

Comment: Session userdata is function that expecting argument. I think this part of code in constructor is not correct: `$this->session->userdata['logged_in'] ['user_id']` and should be something like `$this->session->userdata('item')`. Check [here in docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First you should use base_url instead of site_url in your `$.post` action.
- You aren't sending any data in your like `$.post` request when in your `addlike` function you are using the user_id without assigning any value for it.
- You are repeating $this twice at the first line of your addlike function.
- You are not loading `shoghl_profilat_model` in your `addlike` function how can you use it!
- in your profiles controller construct `$this->profile_id` will mostly be a wrong value because the route will be `profiles/addlike` not containing any IDs.

Fix example:

jQuery aJax code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#likebtn").click(function() {

      $.post(
        "<?=('profiles/addlike/' . $profile_id )?>",
        function(data) {

          if (data.st == 0) {
            $('#likedata').html(data.msg);
          } else if (data.st == 1) {
            $("#Likes").text(st.numLikes);
          }
        },
        'json'
      );
      return false;
    });


  });
</script>
```

Controller/Add link function:

```
public function addlike ( $profile_id ) {

      $this->load->model('shoghl_profilat_model');
      $user_id  = $this->session->userdata('your_id_key'); // don't forget to change that
      $profile_id  = (int) $profile_id;

      $checklike = $this->$this->shoghl_profilat_model->checklike($user_id, $profile_id);

        if ($checklike == FALSE) {

            $this->shoghl_profilat_model->addlike($user_id, $this->profile_id);
            $numLikes = $this->shoghl_profilat_model->likes_profile($this->profile_id);

            $output = array('st' => 1);
            echo json_encode($output);

        } else {

            $outputS = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => "you already likes this profile");

            echo json_encode($output);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the controller in the `addlike function` in the first line

```
$checklike = $this->$this->shoghl_profilat_model->checklike($user_id, $this->profile_id);
```

Notice that the `$this` occurs twice....

Should have been

```
$checklike = $this->shoghl_profilat_model->checklike($user_id, $this->profile_id);
```

Comment: thanks but still when I press the button nothing happens :(

Comment: Are you still getting this error `Object of class profiles could not be converted to string`?

Comment: no, now Message: Undefined property: profiles::$shoghl_profilat_model

Comment: Can you update the code as per the current situation? Also, kindly add the class name line for the model while you are at it....

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a Zend application. In JQuery part, use

```
function likedPost(btnId,likeCount){

  // May be an AJAX call to increment Like for this post...

  $("#likeBtn"+btnId).text(likeCount);

}
```

But before that you'll need to update the Database and get the incremented value of likeCount and then pass it to this function.

In HTML,

```
<a href="javascript:likedPost(123,55);">Like</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didnt got what do you mean ?
my problem is that the like button is not working when I press on it